# Finding the likelihood of a normal distribution in a change point model

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, change-point

The simple change-point problem can be described as follows. Here it is assumed that both $p_1(y)$ and $p_2(y)$ are known completely.

- $y_1,...,y_\tau|\tau $ are iid with distribution $p_1(y)$ and $y_{\tau + 1},...,y_n|\tau$ are iid as $p_2(y)$ and $\tau$ takes the values $1,...,n-1$
- If $\tau = 0$ it is assumed that $y_1,...,y_n|\tau = 0$, are iid $p_2(y)$
- If $\tau = n$ it is assumed that $y_1,...,y_n|\tau = n$, are iid $p_1(y)$

The case $\tau = n$ corresponds to 'No change' and $\tau < n$ to 'change'.

---

I have solved the posterior to be: 
$$p(\tau|y) \propto \bigg[\prod_{j=1}^{\tau} p_1(y_j) \cdot \prod_{j = \tau + 1}^{n} p_2(y_j)\bigg] \cdot p(\tau) $$
I know this is right so I'm not concerned about this part.

---

**The question is this**: Now take $p_1(y)$ to be the normal density with mean $\mu_1$ and precision (reciprocal variance) $\gamma$, and $p_2(y)$ to be the normal density with mean $\mu_2$ and precision (reciprocal
variance) $\gamma$. Note the two distributions have the same precisions. The values of the parameters $\mu_1, \mu_2, \gamma$ are all assumed unknown.

For $\tau$ taking the values $1,...,n-1$ (i.e. at least one observation from each of $p_1$ and $p_2$) **express the likelihood** $p(y|\mu_1, \mu_2 , \gamma, \tau)$ as a function of the parameters $\mu_1, \mu_2 , \gamma, \tau$.

---

Any help as to how this would be expressed is appreciated.

Comment: What is the difficulty in replacing $p_1(y)$ and $p_2(y)$ with the normal pdfs?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? Well, because it's has reciprocal variance I wasn't sure. $p(y|\mu_1, \mu_2 , \gamma, \tau)= \sqrt{\dfrac{\gamma}{2\pi}}\cdot \exp\bigg\{{\dfrac{-\gamma \sum_{j = 1}^{\tau} (y_j-\mu_1)^2}{2}}\bigg\} \cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{\gamma}{2\pi}} \cdot \exp\bigg\{{\dfrac{-\gamma \sum_{j = \tau + 1}^{n} (y_j-\mu_2)^2}{2}}\bigg\}$ @Xi'an

Comment: You have to put either $p_1$ or $p_2$, not the product of the two. Else this is fine. Note that to draw inference on all parameters one needs sufficient numbers of observations on both groups.

Comment: This is a classic homework question and so the full answer should not be given.